# Looking for the "right" way to do a series of matrix-vector products in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 3D `numpy` array `vecs`.  `vecs` has shape `[M,N,3]`.  That is to say, `vecs` is an MxN collection of 3-element vectors.  I am looking for a pythonic (numpythonic?) way to take the matrix product of each of those vectors with a single 3x3 matrix `mat`.  In other words, I want a clean way to do this:

```
>>>    for k in range(vecs.shape[0]):
>>>        for j in range(vecs.shape[1]):
>>>            vecs[k,j] = np.dot(mat, vecs[k,j])
```

Any way to do this?

Comment: Does the result have to be put back into `vecs`, or can it go into another preinitialized array?

Comment: @hpaulj  Another array would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this particular case I think you can just do

```
np.dot(vecs,mat.T)
```

Here is a short snippet of code demonstrating that they are the same:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.random.randn(100,100,3)

In [3]: b = np.random.randn(3,3)

In [4]: expected = np.zeros_like(a)

In [5]: for i in range(a.shape[0]):
   ...:     for j in range(a.shape[1]):
   ...:         expected[i,j] = np.dot(b,a[i,j])
   ...:         

In [6]: np.allclose(expected,np.dot(a,b.T))
Out[6]: True
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `dot`, can be expressed with `einsum` as:

```
res[k,j,:] = np.einsum('ab,b->a',mat,vecs[k,j,:])
```

and generalized to work with the whole array as

```
res = np.einsum('ab,kjb->kja',mat,vecs)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html#numpy.tensordot)

```
vecs = np.tensordot(mat, vecs.T, axes=1).T
```

Here you tranpose your `vecs` to get `(3, M, N)` array in order to 
apply the dot product with `mat` and then transpose the resulting `(3, N, M)` back into `(M, N, 3)` array.

Regarding the `axes` argument:

> If an int N, sum over the last N axes of a and the first N axes of b
>   in order. The sizes of the corresponding axes must match.

So, in your case you sum along the second axis of `mat` with the first axis of `vecs.T`